# tool to know if its n/w problem or the db issue which causing delay

Tags: database, networking, jdbc

I have an application which has some intensive db operation at some point, along with writing blobs. Some time it takes a a lot of time. Is there a tool which can identify if its some network issue and db being slow.

Any pointers would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By using Wireshark, you can sniff the network traffic between your client and server; this might give you an indication of what's going on.

Most database products have monitoring solutions (Oracle has products from TOAD) which provide realtime insight into what's going on in your database.